# RemoteServiceException with no other details

Tags: java, android, exception, android-activity

Recently I started getting lots of RemoteServiceException since last couple weeks in developer console for Android 5.0 and 5.1. There is no stack trace which points to my code present in console.

Attaching stack trace for your reference. If anyone can give idea about where to look, I will be glad.

```
android.app.RemoteServiceException: 



 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1652)

  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:111)

  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:194)

  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5667)

  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)

  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)

  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:962)

  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

Comment: Synchrinize the project and than Clean it, File > Synchronize then : Build > Clean Project.
I hope that will help you all. if this not worked check for `@android:drawable` and put that drawable to your drawable folder

Comment: Hi Abhishek, thanks for quick response. Can you tell me which drawable are you talking about?

Comment: what service are you binding to?

Comment: @AmitBhandari i'm talking about `@android:drawable` replace that with `@drawable` if any used

Comment: @AbhishekSingh drawable? what drawable? where do you see any drawable in the logs?

Comment: @pskink I have one media playback service which I am binding to activity.

Comment: @AbhishekSingh will try that, thanks